# How to create SyntaxFactory.UsingStatement in Roslyn through string

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to populate this type of using statement through Roslyn.

```
Using(var logger = new MethodLogger("someparam"))
{

}
```

How can I generate it..

I am trying this **SyntaxFactory.UsingStatement**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For stuff like this I use [roslynquoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/). It generates roslyn calls out of C# code. For your case it returns something like this:

```
SyntaxFactory
.UsingStatement(SyntaxFactory.Block()/* the code inside the using block */)
.WithDeclaration(SyntaxFactory
    .VariableDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("var"))
    .WithVariables(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(SyntaxFactory
         .VariableDeclarator(SyntaxFactory.Identifier("logger"))
         .WithInitializer(SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(SyntaxFactory
             .ObjectCreationExpression(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(@"MethodLogger"))
             .WithArgumentList(/* arguments for MethodLogger ctor */)))
```

Comment: Man, this could've saved me *so* much time when I was working on some Roslyn stuff...

Comment: Thanks for RoslynQuoter